# Need help with this Huffman coding question

Tags: information

If suppose there are messages m1,m2,m3,m4,m5 with probabilities 0.4, 0.21, 0.18, 0.14 and 0.07. We need to find Huffman encoded output for message sequence m3 m6 m5 m1 m1 m4 m2 m1 m2.

I have solved for Huffman code and i found m1=1, m2=01, m3=001, m4=0000 and m5=0001.
The message sequence has m6 in it. What will be the code for m6. Is there mistake in this question? There are only five messages.

Comment: Are you sure that question is suitable in electrical engineering? Sounds more like signal processing, information theory or mathematics question.

Comment: There is something wrong with the question given to you since the probabilities of the five symbols add to `1.0` so any other symbol (say m6) has probability of occuring being zero. So it is not fair to ask to encode a message which contains that symbol.

Comment: Have you stated the question here *exactly* as it was given to you? Is there more information or context to this question? For mathematicians, a zero probability event can still occur (!) Based on the specific way in which the probabilities are defined/described.

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer to the question "is this question incorrect" depends on how involved your course is. If it's about the algorithm/basics, then probably, as AJN pointed out, since m6 must have probability 0, it can't happen so there's a paradoxon.

**BUT**: If this course actually does a bit about information theory, mutual information, and coding theory, then this question is a question that is meant to make you think about *typical sequences*.

One of the underpinnings of Huffman coding is that you choose messages that don't consist of a single symbol (usually: a 0/1 value) but of a longer sequence.

It can be shown with but two relatively straightforward derivations that as the length of these sequences becomes large, almost certainly all the sequences that appear are "typical", and that therefore all information in the source can be transported by an encoder and decoder that only knows how to deal with these typical sequences. If a sequence isn't typical, it doesn't occur, and not transmitting it or transmitting a different one makes no difference to the error rate. It's asymptotically 0 bit errors for an infinitely long transmission.

So,

- if your course hasn't taught you about concepts such as *entropy*, *mutual information* or *typical sequences*, then the question is paradoxical and can be answered arbitrarily (so, say "doesn't happen; if it happens, wrong assumptions")
- if your course does concern itself with the above terms, or has any mathematical proof for the optimality of Huffman, then you should most definitely arrive at a point where you can say "oh, yeah, tough luck encountering a P(m6)~=0 message, but here's the harm I'm doing, and it's independent of what symbol I choose to encode instead, so I'm picking mX to optimize the only thing I can optimize" (I'm not spelling out what X is here, this should then really be your small success!).